# async function: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Client>`

Tags: rust

I reached a strange error while using recursion inside an async.

I can use `client` inside the `async`. However, if I call `do_something` again it complains about `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Client>` not being send. I think it's trying to send `c` to another thread. I thought `do_something` executed in a thread, and `do_something(client.clone()).await` in another. I don't see why `c` is moving from the `async` thread to this new thread.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::future::Future;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

struct Client{
}

impl Client {}

fn do_something<'a>(
        client: Arc<Mutex<Client>>,
) -> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<(), ()>> {
    async move {
        let c = client.lock().unwrap();
        do_something(client.clone()).await;
        Ok(())
    }.boxed()
}

fn main() {
    let c = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Client{}));
    do_something(c.clone());
}
```

Error:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:17:7
   |
17 |     }.boxed()
   |       ^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: within `impl futures::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Client>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
14 |         let c = client.lock().unwrap();
   |             - has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Client>` which is not `Send`
15 |         do_something(client.clone()).await;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `c` maybe used later
16 |         Ok(())
17 |     }.boxed()
   |     - `c` is later dropped here
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95ca0998613bb48e4e035f69eef1b6fe)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's two problems here, both stemming from the fact that the standard library `Mutex` is designed to be used with regular blocking code, rather than async code:

- Locking the mutex will block the thread, which is generally something you want to avoid in async code as it can prevent other tasks from running.
- As seen in the compiler error, the mutex guard that you get by locking it can't be shared between threads safely, so it won't compile anyways.

Both of these issues can be fixed by using a `Mutex` designed for async code. Since you're already using something from the `futures` crate, you can just use `futures::lock::Mutex`, changing `client.lock().unwrap()` to `client.lock().await`. This version of the lock will yield control back to the task executor when it needs to wait rather than blocking the thread, and will also allow it to be shared between threads if necessary.

The complete version of the code looks like this - however, it's not very useful because you're never actually executing the future returned by `do_something` (note that you're not doing anything with the returned future) and even if you did, it would immediately deadlock due to the recursion:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::future::Future;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};
use futures::lock::Mutex;

struct Client {}

impl Client {}

fn do_something<'a>(
        client: Arc<Mutex<Client>>,
) -> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<(), ()>> {
    async move {
        let c = client.lock().await;
        do_something(client.clone()).await;
        Ok(())
    }.boxed()
}

fn main() {
    let c = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Client {}));
    do_something(c.clone());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50a2f405b1bfecad9135a3c304eb8c1b)

Comment: The `async{}` runs in a thread. `c` never exists this thread, it's created and destructed inside of it. So why I get the error that it cannot be sent between thread safely?

Comment: When you use `async {}`, the rust compiler automatically converts it into a `Future` by making a state machine, where each `.await` causes it to wait for something to happen before transitioning to the next state to continue running. When this wait occurs, control is passed to the executor running your future, and at this point, it could be sent to another thread (e.g. in a multithreaded runtime), so any variables that live across `.await` points need to be `Send` if the future itself is to be `Send` - which `BoxFuture` requires.

Comment: If you're using `tokio`, `tokio::sync::Mutex` has a similar API.